# Parametric Validation of Java Objects

Tags: java, validation

I have a validation project where I need to parse large numbers of records each of which has around 200 fields.  Fields have inter-dependencies from a validation perspective, minimums, maximums and so on.  Some of the rules are expected to change over time.  As a consequence I think I probably need to load the rules from xml?  An extension of this is that I need to be able to generate a detailed error report listing each record and all errors associated with this record.  I have been hunting for validation frameworks that may support this type of functionality and am aware of the more common ones like Hibernate and maybe JValidations, however I am looking for some guidance / recommendations for a well supported flexible framework.

My approach thus far has been to create a validation class that parses the record entity testing each field with "if-then-else" type statements.  This works of course, however it is inflexible and consequently messy to manage - hence my thought that some sort of rules (engine) based approach possibly coded in xml would be better.  Regardless, it would be far beyond my skill level to design such a solution.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: What framework you are using here. struts, Spring ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider [OVal](http://oval.sourceforge.net/) framework for validations and you have an option of Apache Validator and hibernate validator.

Also please refer to [this](http://java-source.net/open-source/validation) link for more details.